# Not possible to unfavorite questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

After unfavoriting a question with version 1.1.0.118 they are still present in the list. However they can be favorited again (so it kind of worked halfway through). On the desktop version they are removed from the list but in the app they are somehow still present in the list (even after refresh or closing the app).

Comment: Is this on iPhone? Which OS version are you using?

Comment: @ArieLitovsky Yes, on the iPhone 5 with iOS8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fixed in the next network build. (No app update required.)  The API wasn't cache busting the /me/favorites request when the favorite status of a question changed.  I had somewhat worked around this by filtering recently removed favorites and appending recently added favorites to the server response but this filtering did not persist between app launches.

I should have just asked Kevin in the first place based on how quickly it was fixed, but there should still be some benefits for poor network connections.